# Couldn't Install HIVE in Hadoop in UBUNTU 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hive

I am trying to install HIVE in my UBUNTU and i am using Oracle-Virtual Box for it in Windows 8. Every tutorial i see have the simple steps for installing HIVE. I did everything like keeping paths in bashrc file, creating a temp directory in hadoop,giving permissions to that folders.

I am getting the following error while running ./hive. 
**database class loader start - derby.database.classpath=''**

Can anyone please help me with this error?

Comment: You don't have your CLASSPATH set. You may have thought you set it correctly, but derby doesn't know where it is. Post the edits you made to your bashrc file. Also post the output of  echo $CLASSPATH. Lastly add more details to your question like the tutorial you followed.

Comment: Actually i solved the issue by downloading mysql and mysql connector. changed my hive-site.xml. Everything is working now.